# How to use component store in a ngrx existed angular project

Tags: angular, ngrx

Can somebody give me an example about how to use component store in an angular app.

in this app the all state management ngrx has be used and also implemented with facade pattern.

I see the component store can create the store, which is only for the component. But I can not find any example, which is also for facede.

Comment: There's great examples in the docs. Note that component store is basically its own facade, so you don't need to integrate it into an existing facade. https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/usage

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a facade for a component store, what's your main reason for this?

That being said, you can create a facade by introducing a wrapper around the component store.

```
@Injectable()
export class MoviesStore extends ComponentStore<MoviesState> {
  
  constructor() {
    super({movies: []});
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class MoviesFacade {
  private store = inject(MoviesStore)
  /* interact with store here */
}
```

The `MoviesFacade` can then be used in the component.